# Passing $data from model to controller and from controller to view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an array ($data) in my model. I would like to pass it to my controller, so the controller can pass it to the view.

**Model:**

```
$data['table'] = $db->get_custom_db($target)->list_tables(); 
return $data;
```

**Controller:**

```
$this->load->view('page', $data);
```

**View:**

```
var_dump($data); // This returns NULL
```

How do I do this?

**Edit:** **This is the full code**

**Controller**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {

        $this->load->model('connection_model');
        $db = new Connection_model();

        if (isset($_SESSION['connection'])) {
            if ($db->get_custom_db('sender') && $db->get_custom_db('receiver')) {

                $this->load->model('readdata_model');
                $readData = new ReadData_model();

                $readData->get_table('sender');
                $this->layout->load_template('tables', 'Data Migrator: Overview');
            }
        }
        else {
            // Load the template of Home
            $this->layout->load_template('home', 'Data Migrator: Home');
        }
    }
}
```

**Layout.php (libraries)**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Layout {
    protected $ci;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->ci =& get_instance();
    }

    public function load_template($page, $title, $full_template = true, $model = NULL, $model_position = 'top') {
        if (file_exists(APPPATH . 'views/pages/' . $page . '.php')) {
            $data['page_title'] = $title;

            if ($model_position != 'top' && $model_position != 'bottom') {
                exit('Error: Bad parameter (' . $model_position . '). Please use "top" or "bottom" instead.');
            }

            // Building the template
            if ($full_template) {
                $this->ci->load->view('template/header', $data);
                if ($model && $model_position == 'top') {
                    $model;
                }
            }
            $this->ci->load->view('pages/' . $page, $data);
            if ($model && $model_position == 'bottom') {
                $model;
            }
            if ($full_template) {
                $this->ci->load->view('template/footer');
            }
        }
        else {
            show_404();
        }
    }

}
```

**Model**

```
<?php
class ReadData_model extends CI_Model {
    public function get_table($target) {
        if ($target != 'sender' && $target != 'receiver') { exit('Error: Illegal parameter. Please use sender or receiver instead.'); }
        $this->load->model('Connection_model');
        $db = new Connection_model();

        $data['table'] = $db->get_custom_db($target)->list_tables();
        return $data;    
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<?php
var_dump($table);
```

Comment: Can you post full files?

Comment: can you post the block of code where you call model in controller?

Comment: I have updated my question. You can see the full code now.

Answer (score 1):

In your view, don't try to print `$data['index']`, but instead: `$index`. That's how Codeigniter works.

So in your code, `$table` should be accessible in the view, not `$data['table']`.

Comment: I also tried using $table. It still returns NULL and the error _Undefined variable: table_. I have updated my question. Please take a look at the whole code. I am sure the issue must be somewhere else.

Comment: What about `$page_title`, can you print it in your view?

Comment: Yes, I get the value of $page_title.